# Basis of the null space

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Find the basis of the null space for the matrix

$$D = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 &1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

I computed the solution by letting eigenvectors $(x,y,z,w)$ such that $y+z=0,x+y=0$, and I got a basis vector $\{(1,-1,1,0), (0,0,0,1)\}$ . But from one textbook  I have found the solution as $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,1)\}$. May I made a mistake? Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is correct. The textbook solution is wrong, it appears to be a null space for $D^\top$ (with one sign error).

Comment: @McFry.. Thank you for your alarm response.

Comment: It's also possible that your textbook has matrices act on the right.  For instance, $(1,0,0,0) \cdot D = 0$.

Comment: I agree with @SpamIAm. That explanation fits perfectly.  You need to check your textbook, whether the matrices act on the vectors from the right or from the left. In linear algebra texts they often act from the left, but there are advantages to doing it the other way, too. All depending on the context and on the preferences of the author. You cannot rely on all the authors adopting the same convention.