# Factor $f(x) = x^4+x^2+x+1$ over $F_2$ by using the Berlekamp's algorithm.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, change-of-basis

> Factor $f(x) = x^4+x^2+x+1$ over $F_2$ by using the Berlekamp's algorithm.

Here to factor the polynomial $f(x)$ I did the following steps.

Step 1. $\gcd(f(x), f'(x)) = 1$ and $f(x)$ has no repeated factors.

step 2. compute the powers $x^{2i} \bmod f(x)$ for $0 \leq i \leq 3$. This yields the following congruences:
$$x^0=  1 \bmod f,\ x^2 = x^2 \bmod f,\ x^4 = 1 + x + x^2 \bmod f,\
x^6 = 1 + x + x^3 \bmod f.$$

Step 3. So, the matrix $D$ of order 4 by 4 is given as
$$D = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\1 &1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
and the matrix $D-I$ is

$$D-I = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 &1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Step 4.  Compute the basis of the null space for the matrix.

Here is my confusion.
I computed the solution by letting eigenvectors $(x,y,z,w)$ such that $-y+z=0,x+y=0$, and I got a basis vector $\{(1,-1,-1,0), (0,0,0,1)\}$ . But from one textbook  I have found the solution as $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,1)\}.$ Did I make a mistake? Hereafter it is easy. Thanks!

Comment: [You asked almost the same question once before. Edit your previous question instead of posting a new one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734068/basis-of-the-null-space?noredirect=1) Again, you are correct and the textbook is wrong.

Comment: @McFry... yes, but I am afraid that the problem may be followed from the above steps(from the algorithm behavior).

Comment: @McFry : as a matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$, the book gives the correct null space for $D^T$

Comment: @ UserAb : why don't you finish the algorithm and see if you get the correct factorization ? (????)  your job is proving why the algorithm works or doesn't... for example you write $D-I$ and your vectors with some $-1$ as if those were not some matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$, are you sure it is correct ?)

Comment: @user1952009... The book finally puts the desired factor
ization as $f(x) = (x + 1)(x^3 + x^2 + 1)$, but before that it puts the matrix $$D-I = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 &1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ in step 3 above (i.e. '1' instead of '-1'). That is my confusion.

Comment: @ UserAb : yes you understood now that everything is in $\mathbb{F}_2$. I can't prove how (and why) the Berlekamp algorithm works, that's what you have to do now.